# Why does Apache need stop and start (rather than restart) for new PHP version to take effect?

Tags: apache2, php

On Ubuntu 18 running Apache 2.4 with mod_php.

Whenever we get a package update for PHP, restarting Apache using `apachectl graceful` or `apachectl restart` doesn't end up with the new PHP version taking effect.  However, `apachectl stop` followed by `apachectl start` does reload the correct version of PHP.

Why is this?

Comment: Ubuntu 18?   Do you mean Ubuntu Core 18? or Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ? or something else?  The *year* format release, are different products to the more common *year.month* products; the *year* products are *snap* only so everything is containerized, thus impacting configs.  Please specific your release, as there is no Ubuntu 18.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache loads the php module (among many other modules) when it starts. `apachectl restart` - according to description in `man apachectl` - just sends SIGHUP to the Apache process currently residing in memory, telling it to kill all it's children (or, in case of *graceful* restart, which is SIGUSR1 instead of SIGHUP, just wait until they finish) and then start over, forking the children again. It does not reload the program binaries again from disk.

If you stop Apache then start it again, all running processes are removed from memory and are again loaded from disk.

There seems to be some semantic inconsistency between meaning of "restart" in `apachectl restart` command and `service apache2 restart` command (or whatever the Apache service is called instead of `apache2`). The latter actually stops and starts the service, while `apachectl restart` is equivalent of `service apache2 reload`. Note "reload" instead of "restart".

Comment: I find this odd though, because all virtual host configurations are reloaded via a restart, and I'm sure various other modules can be enabled and disabled via a restart.  So it puzzles me why a start and stop is required for the correct PHP binary to take effect.

Comment: Rereading the configuration is not the same as reloading program binaries. From my experience, whenever I changed a set of enabled/disabled modules, I needed to restart Apache completely. However, I did not test it very thoroughly.

Comment: Very surprised that `restart` differs from `stop` and `start`, but you must be correct as there is no other explanation

Comment: From `man apachectl`: "restart       Restarts  the  Apache  daemon by sending it a SIGHUP." This is very different from doing "stop", then "start". However, `service apache2 restart` (or whatever the service is called) instead of `apachectl restart` **probably** would do what you want.

Comment: Great explanation of the differences, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because that restarts the apache server. You need to also do

```
service php7.4-fpm restart
```

to restart the application server (change the 7.4 (it is the default on 20.10) to your version; and it could also be a totally different service; I used FPM as an example).

Comment: Apache is running as MPM Prefork, so I don't think this is the case

Comment: What does the 1st part has to do with the 2nd part? How apache addresses multiprocessing has no impact on the application server?

Comment: Because we are running PHP as an Apache module, so you restart it by restarting Apache.  If you are running Apache as worker or event, then PHP is independent and would be restarted as you've suggested